# magento - unable to save products in cart

Tags: magento-1.8, cart

am working magento payment gateway.

```
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

$product_id = $product_model->getIdBySku('inv_'.$code);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);



// Add to cart (?)
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'related_product' => null,
    'qty' => 1
);
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
//$cart->removeItem($product_id)->save();
$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);


$cart->save();
```

but when I refresh cart page then no new product added in to cart

Edited :

I found product is added in cart also i checked by output values

```
var_dump($cart->getQuote()->getHasError());
$products = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
var_dump(count($products));
```

Then i can see new product added count is two but when i refresh cart page then can't see second product added by code

Comment: you say that it is shown in the `getAllItems` I would be interested in finding out what `getAllVisibleItems` returns

Answer (score 2):

Try to run

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

after

```
$cart->save();
```

Comment: i have try this also, not working this

Comment: Are you sure that your $_product contains product information?

Comment: yes i have checked

Comment: please check i have updated my question may be you can now identify problem